# How to get IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 to offer suggestions on importing the right packages to resolve symbols?

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, intellij-idea

How do I get IntelliJ IDEA to offer suggestions to resolve an unresolved symbol like Visual Studio does like in the picture below?

[image]

I wanted to use **Aspose Cells for Java** in a console application, so I downloaded the relevant JAR file and added a reference to it like so:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies Tab -> + sign
```

[image]

I am not sure why I do not see the library reference in the **External Libraries** node of the treeview on the left side.

[image]

Anyway, just because I wasn't sure, I also added the JAR files I needed to a newly created folder which I named **lib** and added that lib folder as a library like so:

[image]

Now, when I type in some code, the intellisense reports that it cannot resolve the symbol `Workbook`.

So, I qualify the type `Workbook` with its full name like so:

`com.aspose.cells.Workbook` and that symbols is resolved. To resolve all the symbols, I add the `import com.aspose.cells.*` statement on the top and the symbols are all resolved.

I was wondering why, like Visual Studio offers a suggestion for you to add the namespace on the top, does IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 not give me suggestions to add the relevant `import` statement so I don't have to type it myself or even know what the correct import statement is?

Does it have such a feature? How do I use that feature?

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If it doesn't help, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the red line(Error line).

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then choose `import class` or(Something like this);